# neural network error is a matrix

Tags: neural-network, python-3.6

i recently made a simple neural network, and i found that the error is a matrix when its supposed to be a single number, which causes the output to change from a simple 4*1 matrix to a 4*20 matrix, can someone pleas help me figure out how i have to redefine the error to change the l5_error into a 4*1 matrix while preserving the accuracy of the network

```
<import numpy as np

def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if (deriv == True):
        return (x * (1 - x))
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

X = np.array([[1,1,0],
              [0,1,1],
              [0,0,1],
              [1, 0, 0]])

y = np.array([[0],
              [1],
              [0],
              [1]])

np.random.seed(1)


syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((len(X[1]), 100)) - 1
syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((100, 80)) - 1
syn2 = 2 * np.random.random((80, 60)) - 1
syn3 = 2 * np.random.random((60, 40)) - 1
syn4 = 2 * np.random.random((40, 20)) - 1
syn5 = 2 * np.random.random((20, 1)) - 1

#the layers are only defined here so i can see the dimensions of the error
l0 = X
l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0))
l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1, syn1))
l3 = nonlin(np.dot(l2, syn2))
l4 = nonlin(np.dot(l3, syn3))
l5 = nonlin(np.dot(l4, syn4))
l5_error = y - l5
print('beggining', l5_error, 'ending')

for i in range(1000):
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0))
    l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1, syn1))
    l3 = nonlin(np.dot(l2, syn2))
    l4 = nonlin(np.dot(l3, syn3))
    l5 = nonlin(np.dot(l4, syn4))
    l5_error = y - l5
    if (i % 10) == 0:
        print( "Error: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(l5_error))))

    print(l5_error, nonlin(l5, deriv=True))
    l5_delta = l5_error * nonlin(l5, deriv=True)

    l4_error = l5_delta.dot(syn4.T)

    l4_delta = l4_error * nonlin(l4, deriv=True)

    l3_error = l4_delta.dot(syn3.T)

    l3_delta = l3_error * nonlin(l3, deriv=True)

    l2_error = l3_delta.dot(syn2.T)

    l2_delta = l2_error * nonlin(l2, deriv=True)

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1, deriv=True)

    #syn5 += l5.T.dot(l6_delta)
    syn4 += l4.T.dot(l5_delta)
    syn3 += l3.T.dot(l4_delta)
    syn2 += l2.T.dot(l3_delta)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)

print ("Output after training")
print (l5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mistake in the definition of l5_error, it should be

```
l5_error = np.linalg.norm(y-l5)
```

This same issue occurs some of the other error variables; simply add a call np.linalg.norm to each.

Comment: Output after training
[[ 1.          1.          0.99925221  1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.        ]

Comment: [ 1.          1.          0.99924249  1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          0.99923739  1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.        ]